# How could I remove duplicates if duplicates mean less than 30days?

Tags: sql, pandas

(using sql or pandas)
I want to delete records if the Date difference between two records is less than 30 days.
But first record of ID must be remained.

```
#example
ROW ID  DATE  
1   A   2020-01-01 -- first  
2   A   2020-01-03  
3   A   2020-01-31  
4   A   2020-02-05  
5   A   2020-02-28  
6   A   2020-03-09  
7   B   2020-03-06 -- first  
8   B   2020-05-07  
9   B   2020-06-02
```

---

```
#expected results
ROW ID  DATE  
1   A   2020-01-01  
4   A   2020-02-05  
6   A   2020-03-09  
7   B   2020-03-06  
8   B   2020-05-07
```

ROW 2,3 are within 30 days from ROW 1
ROW 5 is within 30 days from ROW 4
ROW 9 is within 30 days from ROW 8

Comment: difference compared to the first date or most recent ?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are running: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: explain better what the criteria for comparing the dates are. It is very ambiguous in the current form

Comment: fist date would be starting point.
If second date is after 30 days from first date, then second date would be new starting point.  If not, that row should be removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cope with your task it is not possible to call any
vectorized methods.

The cause is that after a row is recognized as a duplicate, then
this row "does not count" when you check further rows.

E.g. after rows *2020-01-03* and *2020-01-31* were deleted (as
"too close" to the previous row) then *2020-02-05* row should be
left, because now the distance to the previous row (*2020-01-01*)
is big enough.

So I came up with a solution based on a "function with memory":

```
def isDupl(elem):
    if isDupl.prev is None:
        isDupl.prev = elem
        return False
    dDiff = (elem - isDupl.prev).days
    rv = dDiff <= 30
    if not rv:
        isDupl.prev = elem
    return rv
```

This function should be invoked for each *DATE* in the
current group (with same *ID*) but before that *isDupl.prev*
must be set to *None*.

So the function to apply to each group of rows is:

```
def isDuplGrp(grp):
    isDupl.prev = None
    return grp.DATE.apply(isDupl)
```

And to get the expected result, run:

```
df[~(df.groupby('ID').apply(isDuplGrp).reset_index(level=0, drop=True))]
```

(you may save it back to *df*).

The result is:

```
   ROW ID       DATE
0    1  A 2020-01-01
3    4  A 2020-02-05
5    6  A 2020-03-09
6    7  B 2020-03-06
7    8  B 2020-05-07
```

And finally, a remark about the other solution:
It contains rows:

```
3    4  A 2020-02-05
4    5  A 2020-02-28
```

which are only **23** days apart, so this solution is **wrong**.

The same pertains to rows:

```
5  A 2020-02-28
6  A 2020-03-09
```

which are also too close in time.

Comment: This is exactly what I want, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. Convert date to `datetime64`
2. Get the first date from each group `df.groupby('ID')['DATE'].transform('first')`
3. Add a filter to keep only dates greater than 30 days
4. Append the first date  of each group to the dataframe

**Code:**

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])

df1 = df[(df['DATE'] - df.groupby('ID')['DATE'].transform('first')) >= pd.Timedelta(30, unit='D')]
df1 = df1.append(df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg('first')).sort_values(by=['ID', 'DATE'])
print(df1)


   ROW ID       DATE
0    1  A 2020-01-01
2    3  A 2020-01-31
3    4  A 2020-02-05
4    5  A 2020-02-28
5    6  A 2020-03-09
1    7  B 2020-03-06
7    8  B 2020-05-07
8    9  B 2020-06-02
```